# Patterns for present tense verb conjugation

Tags: граматика, дієслова, дієвідмінювання, conjugation

> **This question also has an answer here (in Ukrainian):**
>   *[Простий спосіб визначення дієвідміни: -уть (-ють) проти -ать (-ять)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1260)*

I'm aware that there are four sets of present tense endings, each named by their third person plural. They are separated into two sets of iotified pairs. first conjugation (`-уть`, `-ють`) and second conjugation (`-ать`, `-ять`).

Are there any rules or generalizations about which verbs take first conjugation and which verbs take second conjugation? I understand that the non-iotified ending is used after a consonant and the iotified one after a vowel.

---

Мені відомо, що існує чотири закінчення теперішнього часу, кожне з яких назване за третьою особою множини. Вони розділені на два набори йотованих пар: першої дієвідміни (`-уть`, `-ють`) та другої дієвідміни (`-ать`, `-ять`).

Чи існує яке-небудь правило або узагальнення, які дієслова відносять до першої дієвідміни і які дієслова відносять до другої дієвідміни? Я розумію, що нейотоване закінчення використовується після приголосного, а йотоване після голосної.

Comment: Ukrainian Wikipedia has [Дієвідмінювання дієслів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.94.D1.96.D1.94.D0.B2.D1.96.D0.B4.D0.BC.D1.96.D0.BD.D1.8E.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F_.D0.B4.D1.96.D1.94.D1.81.D0.BB.D1.96.D0.B2) article.

Comment: Added a header notice according to https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ — not sure however if this is applicable to bilingual questions, but anyway, the existing answer here is English-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any rules or generalizations about which verbs take first conjugation and which verbs take second conjugation?

**Yes, but you need more than just an infinitive**.

**Caveat**, your question specifically calls 1st and 2nd conjugation groups by its endings `-уть/-ють` and `-ать/-ять`, respectively. I believe this is how it is called in your textbook.
This answer *also* relies on observation about how the verbs conjugate in 3rd person plural.
I admit this looks like a dead loop, but I believe this is the most academic way how we define these conjugation groups. Also, this answer is useful if you know what form a verb takes in 1st person singular.

---

[This article](http://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/88.html) has a great writeup, let me formalize it in most succinct manner:

Most verbs belong to the 1st conjugation group.

A verb belongs to the 2nd group if any of below is true:

1. its root ends with `-и-`, `-і-`, `-ї-` and also `-жа-`, `-ча-`, `-ша-`

   - **and** the end vowel **drops** in 1st person singular or 3rd person plural
2. verbs ending with `-отіти`
3. several verbs not belonging to rules listed above:

   - *стоя-ти* {to stand} (root ends with `-я`)
   - *боя-тися* {to be scared} (root ends with `-я`)
   - *спа-ти* {to sleep} (root ends with `-а-`, but not after `ж/ч/ш`)
   - *біг-ти* {to run} (root ends with consonant)

---

Several examples to explain vowel drop in **1st person singular** and **3rd person plural**; I marked with underscore (**_**) the place where the vowel dropped:

- *ба́ч**и**-ти / ба́ч**_**-у / ба́ч**_**-ать* — root ends with `-и-`, and it drops → 2nd group {to see}
- *ж**и́**-ти / ж**и**в-у́ / ж**и**в-у́ть* — root ends with `-и-`, and it does not drop → 1st group {to live}
- *сид**і́**-ти / сид**_**ж-у́ / сид**_**-я́ть* — root ends with `-і-`, and it drops → 2nd group {to sit}
- *біл**і́**-ти / біл**і́**-ю / біл**і́**-ють*  — root ends with `-і-`, and it does not drop → 1st group {to whiten}
- *кри**ча́**-ти / крич**_**-у́ / крич**_**-а́ть* — root ends with `-ча-`, and `-а-` drops → 2nd group {to scream}
- *поста**ча́**-ти / поста**ча́**-ю / поста**ча́**-ють* — root ends with `-ча-`, and `-а-` does not drop → 1st group {to deliver}

This verb is tricky; it has two forms, one for 1st conjugation group and one for the 2nd. Note, they both have exactly equivalent meaning {to bubble}:

- *бульк-**оті́**-ти / булькоч-у́ / бульк-отя́ть* — root ends with `-оті-` → 2nd group
- *бульк-**ота́**-ти / булькоч-у́ / булько́ч-уть* — root ends with `-ота-` → 1nd group

Comment: If I were to have to guess for a random word whether the end vowel of a stem ending with `и`, `і`, `ї`, `жа`, `ча`, or `ша` is dropped, would it be better to guess that it is or that it isn't?

Comment: @FracturedRetina, not sure what is "better". In some words it drops, in some words it does not. Or maybe I misunderstood the comment?

Comment: I meant if i didn't know, is one more common than the other and therefore a safer bet?

Comment: @FracturedRetina, ah, this… Hmm, interesting… Not sure if I can answer. **By number**, I believe that most verbs belong to the 1st group. But the problem is that many 2nd group verbs are widely used in common speak, like *to see*, *to run*, *to sit*. I can't suggest anything beyond just memorizing them.