# Простий спосіб визначення дієвідміни: -уть (-ють) проти -ать (-ять)

Tags: дієслова, дієвідмінювання

> **Це запитання також має відповідь (англійською):**
>   *[Patterns for present tense verb conjugation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1224)*

З уроків української мови я пам'ятаю, що дієслова мають різні дієвідміни, які чітко визначають закінчення в 3-й особі множини тепершнього часу, наприклад:

> - сид**ять**
> - стеж**ать**

проти

> - стриж**уть**
> - співа**ють**

Але в деяких словах правильне закінчення є досить неочевидним, наприклад:

> - сипл**ять** чи сипл**ють**
> - бач**уть** чи бач**ать**

Чи є якесь просте і зрозуміле правило для визначення правильної форми будь-якого дієслова?

Comment: Мені здається, в тих випадках, коли Вам важко визначити — ви просто живете на перетині різних діалектів, в одному з яких кажуть так, а в іншому — інакше. Тобто фактично (не за нормами офіційного правопису, а як люди кажуть) правильно і так, і так. Наприклад, в мене аніяких сумнівів, що тільки «бач**а**ть» — але при цьому я чув людей, що кажуть «баче», «ходе» (і, відповідно, в них має бути й «бачуть», «ходють»).

Comment: [Сипати](http://sum.in.ua/s/sypaty): «Шумів ліс, віючи холодом в душі танкістів, сипл**ю**чи жар в їхні серця» (Юрій Яновський), «Поки гестапівець, сипл**я**чи прокльонами, сичав і зводився з землі на ноги, .. в полі, недалеко від села, спалахнуло червоне полум'я» (Дмитро Бедзик).

Comment: Тут я згоден, але все ж не скрізь це працює, мені здається. Наприклад, я не можу собі уявити `стрижать` або `сидють`. І все ж хотілося б знати правильну форму з точки зору українського правопису.

Comment: Ви, звісно, можете звертатися до інших форм, що у Вас у пам'яті зафіксувалися більше, наприклад, можливо, 3-ї особи однини («„ходе“ чи „ходить“?») — але якщо Ви справді живете на перетині (одні кажуть так, інші — інакше), то навряд чи це Вам допоможе. Лише дивитися в словники (в правописі [є](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par80p2) правила поділу на дієвідміни, але вони доволі нетривіальні, як на мене).

Comment: Додав шапку відповідно до https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Професор Ющук І.П., [Практикум з правопису і граматики української мови](https://ushchuk.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/d196.pdf) (2012).

> **§ 82. Правопис закінчень дієслів у теперішньому і простому майбутньому часах**
>
> Дієслова в теперішньому часі (*щ о р о б л ю ? щ о р о б и ш ?* і
>   т.д.) і в простому майбутньому (*щ о з р о б л ю ? щ о з р о б и ш ?*
>   і т.д.) змінюються однаково.
>
> За характером закінчень дієслова в цих часах діляться на **дві
>   дієвідміни**.
>
> ...
>
> 1. До **першої дієвідміни** належать дієслова, які в усіх особах, крім 1-ї особи однини і 3-ї ооби множини, в закінченнях мають ***–е-
>      (-є-)***, а в 3-й особі множини закінчення *–уть (-ють)*: *`пишеш`,
>      `пише`, `пишемо`, `пишете`, `пишуть`; `співаєш`, `співає`, `співаємо`,
>      `співаєте`, `співають`*. До **другої дієвідміни** належать дієслова,
>      які в усіх особах, крім 1-ї особи однини і 3-ї ооби множини, в
>      закінченнях мають ***–и- (-ї-)***, а в 3-й особі множини закінчення
>      ***-ать (-ять)***: *`мовчиш`, `мовчить`, `мовчимо`, `мовчите`, `мовчать`; `стоїш`, `стоїть`, `стоїмо`, `стоїте`, `стоять`*.
> 2. Дієвідміна дієслова весь час залишається тою самою. Тому, **щоб перевірити, що написати в закінченні: букву *е* чи *и*, *є* чи *ї*;
>      закінчення –*уть* чи –
>      *ать*, *-ють* чи *-ять*, — досить за будь-якою особою визначити дієвідміну цього дієслова**. Наприклад, чуємо [*дишиемо*] і вагаємося,
>      яку букву писати в закінченні: *е* чи *и*. Змінюємо дієслово:
>      [*`дише`*] — виразно чується закінчення *-е*; отже, й у попередній
>      формі треба написати *е*: *`дишемо`*. Так само чуємо [*сидеите*], а
>      пишемо *`сидите`*, бо в закінченні форми [*`сидитˊ`*] чітко звучить
>      *и*, не *е*.
>      **Найчастіше правопис закінчень перевіряють за 3-ю особою множини:
>      *`несемо`*, бо *`несуть`* (І дієвідміна); *`сидимо`*, бо *`сидять`* (II дієвідміна), але можна це так само робити за 3-ю особою однини**
>
> **§ 83. Визначення дієвідміни дієслова за його неозначеною формою**
>
> **Іноді важко визначити дієвідміну дієслова за особовими закінченнями — вони чуються невиразно.** Наприклад, можемо вимовити
>   [*`бореицˊцˊа`*] і [*`бориецˊцˊа`*], [*`борˊуцˊцˊа`*] і
>   ]*`борˊацˊцˊа`*], але писати треба лише **`бореться`**,
>   **`борються`**. 
>   **У такому разі дієвідміну дієслова визначаємо за його неозначеною формою.**
>
> **Якщо в неозначеній формі перед `-ти` дієслово має суфікс `-і-` `(-ї-)`, `-и-` або після шиплячого `-а-` і цей суфікс у 1-й особі
>   однини (щ о р о б л ю ? ) випадає, то це дієслово належить до II
>   дієвідміни. Інші дієслова належать до І дієвідміни.**
>
> Наприклад, у дієсловах `белькотіти` — `белькочу`, `кроїти` — `крою`,
>   `волочити` — `волочу`, `стелити` — `стелю`, `мовчати` — `мовчу` в 1-й
>   особі однини суфікси `-і-`, `-и-` та після шиплячого `-а-`
>   випадають—отже, ці дієслова належать до **II дієвідміни**:
>   `белькотиш`, `кроїш`, `волочиш`, `стелиш`, `мовчиш` і т. д.
>
> А в дієсловах `радіти` — `радію`, `захищати` — `захищаю` суфікси `-і-`
>   та `-а-` не випадають—отже, ці дієслова належать до **І дієвідміни**:
>   `радієш`, `захищаєш` і т. д.
>
> У дієсловах `белькотати`, `полоти`, `в’янути`, `волокти` нема названих
>   вище суфіксів — отже, ці дієслова належать до **І дієвідміни**:
>   `белькочеш`, `полеш`, `в’янеш`, `волочеш` і т. д.
>
> У дієсловах `бити`, `пити`, `лити`. `жати`, `почати` звуки [`и`] та
>   [`а`] не суфікси — отже, ці дієслова також належать до **І
>   дієвідміни**: `б’єш`, `п’єш`, `ллєш`, `жнеш` або `жмеш`, `почнеш` і т.
>   д.
>
> Із цього правила є **винятки**:
>
> а) дієслова `хотіти`, `гудіти`, `сопіти`, `ревіти`, `іржати` і похідні
>   належать до
>   **І дієвідміни**: `хочеш`, гудеш, `сопеш`, `ревеш`, `іржеш` і т.д. (хоч за всіма ознаками мали б належати до ІІ дієвідміни);
>
> б) дієслова `бігти`, `боятися`, `стояти`, `спати` і похідні належать
>   до **II дієвідміни**: `біжиш`, `боїшся`, `стоїш`, `спиш` і т.д. (хоч
>   за всіма ознаками мали б належати до І дієвідміни);
>
> в) дієслово `сукати` може належати **і до І, і до II дієвідміни**:
>   `сукаю`, `сукаєш` і т.д. або `сучу`, `сучиш` і т.д.

І додає пан професор такі поради.

> **Та це ж просто...**
>
> ***К м і т л и в и й*** .
>
> **Коротше кажучи, випадають суфікси `-и-`, `-і-`, `-(ш)а-` — отже, це *II дієвідміна*, пиши в закінченнях `и`. Не випадають або їх нема —*І дієвідміна*, пиши `е`. А винятки легко перевірити за 3-ю особою
>   однини: `хоче`, `гуде`, `сопе`, `реве`, `ірже`, `біжить`, `стоїть`,
>   `боїться`, `спить`.**
>
> ***Д о п и т л и в и й*** .
>
> **Деякі дієслова, хоча звучать майже однаково і мають однакове значення, належать до різних дієвідмін через те, що в них *різні
>   суфіки в неозначеній формі*: `хропти` і `хропіти`, `волокти` і
>   `волочити`, `слатися` і `стелитися`, `бурмотати` і `бурмотіти`,
>   `свистати` і `свистіти`... Отже, як їх не напишеш — буде правильно:
>   `хропеш` і `хропиш`, `стелеться` і `стелиться`, `бурмочеш` і
>   `бурмотиш`... Але не “`бурмочиш`”!**